# Robot Framework with PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I am totally new to automation and trying to learn RobotFramework. I am trying to write the scripts following some video guide. Usually robot scripts  autocomplete in PyCharm IDE with desired color. I found the whole script along with 4 sections(Settings, Variables, Test cases and Keywords) are in green. Not sure how to change that thing.

```
***  Settings ***
Doumentation  This is some basic info about the whole suite

Library   Selenium2Library


*** variables ***


***  Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
    [Documentation]  This is somebasic information about the test
    [Tags]   Smoke
    Open browser   http://www.amazon.com  chrome
    Close browser


***  keywords ***
```

Also when I am running this scripts I am getting error

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'tests/amazon.robot' failed: File has no test case table.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the dedicated IDE, [RIDE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-ride)? It was kind of buggy before, but a lot of work has been done, and it works very well now. I strongly recommend giving it a shot, it makes the work a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two or more spaces between `***` and `Test Cases`, and between `***` and `Settings`. In the format you're using, two spaces mark the separation between two cells in a table row. The string `*** Test Cases ***` needs to all be in a single cell.

Comment: Thnks it worked, though I am getting other error. I have installed Selenium2Library, but still 'Open Bowser keyword' is not getting recognised.Importing test library 'Selenium2library' failed: ImportError: No module named Selenium2library

Comment: based on the error message, you either don't have it installed or it can't be seen in the path variable